# Page scroll menu not working Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have created my first microsite with Umbraco/ASP.NET at [www.surreyhillsmt.co.uk](http://www.surreyhillsmt.co.uk). I started with a bootstrap theme called Agency from startbootstrap.com, and find that the smooth page scrolling from my menu works on the Edge browser and both Safari and Firefox on an iPhone/iPad.

However, smooth page scrolling does not work on either Firefox or Chrome on a PC (fully updated Windows 10, and both Firefox and Chrome installed within last couple of days). This problem is not exhibited by the static bootstrap theme that I used.

I would really appreciate any help. By way of background I am competent with C# and okay with HTML/CSS. I have zero knowledge of javascript and the like.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer a problem. Oddly this was fixed with the passage of time. I guess it was a caching related issue.